# crash on android with phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a HTML5 application for Android.
Everything is fine all pages through application, but when it comes to an specific page of app it crashes.

The crash occurs only in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1). earlier. I tested with Dell Streak 5" (Android 2.3.2) and ZTE-Blade (Android 2.2) and there wasn't any problem.

In that page, there is an AJAX call, and then creating a dynamic HTML form elements and also using geolocation of phonegap.

The most interesting part is that I can't see any error related to my app when I look at LogCat in Eclipse. but some dumps about device at the and my app crashes.

Note: using jquery mobile 1.0 RC2, phonegap 1.2.0 (tested with 1.1.0 and 1.0.0)

Here is some part of the log:

```
I/DEBUG(22434): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

I/DEBUG(22434): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:3.1/HMJ37/XWKGB:user/release-keys'

I/DEBUG(22434): pid: 27352, tid: 27361  >>> com.test.forms <<<

I/DEBUG(22434): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0086c000

I/DEBUG(22434):  r0 008673e0  r1 0086bff4  r2 0000037c  r3 00000000

I/DEBUG(22434):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000028  r7 00000000

I/DEBUG(22434):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000

I/DEBUG(22434):  ip 0086c000  sp 5c3db7f0  lr a8291663  pc aff0c9a8  cpsr 20000010

E/DBG_WSS_DM(25618): Warning!!! [wssTelephonyData.java Line:167] getInstance PHONE_TYPE_NONE

E/(234): RIL_onMultiClientUnsolicitedResponse:

E/(234): unsupported multiclient unsolicited response code 1002

E/(234): RIL_onMultiClientUnsolicitedResponse:

E/(234): unsupported multiclient unsolicited response code 1002

E/DBG_WSS_DM(25618): Warning!!! [wssTelephonyData.java Line:167] getInstance PHONE_TYPE_NONE

I/System.out(385): [INFO:404673809]: LogSource: Running flush

I/System.out(385): [INFO:404673810]: LogSource: Sending payload [bytes=388]

I/dumpstate(27428): done

I/WindowManager(290): WIN DEATH: Window{40d93e38 com.test.forms/com.test.forms.FormsActivity paused=false}

I/ActivityManager(290): Process com.test.forms (pid 27352) has died.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning!!! [wssTelephonyData.java Line:167] getInstance PHONE_TYPE_NONE
```

Checking your log this line makes me think that the reason why it only occurs on Galaxy Tab 10.1 is that because it doesnt have a Telephony and that's why it's making the application crash in a weird way.Phonegap is good but still have some irritating bugs that which is pretty hard to workaround.
As you mentioned the others device you use both have Telephony so i think that's the reason .

Comment: well, thanks, but it crashes only in a specific page not in all pages of app. besides, i don't use any thing related to phone.

yes Galaxy is not a phone, so it must blow every page or first page of app, not a specific page.

Comment: Well like i said before Phonegap is still kinda buggy and can give your hard times debugging i assume that there's some stuff at that specific page which makes Phonegap crash.Can you give specific info about the page that it's crashing

Comment: only thing related to phonegap in that page is geolocation. it crashes as well even if i comment geolocation code block. there isn't any other special thing but pure html via jqmobile.

there is an ajax call in that page, i fetch some data from server for html web form inside that page. i create textboxes, comboboxes on the fly etc. that's all. 

actually i think that the error occurs because jqmobile or phonegap framework can't handle so much controls(i.e. 20 dorpdownlist), so it crashes, if i create less html form control after ajax call it works, but when there are many controls it crashes.

Comment: If you say so then it's probably framework related crash cause of JQM.Have you tried using other frameworks like Sencha it's also pretty good for your purpose it's really good.

Comment: no i didn't try, bu i aware of them. does it take so long switching to sencha?
btw, there isn't such error in PC web browsers like Opera, Chrome, Firefox...

Comment: Well built in Android Webkit browser is kinda different from those so that's why their responses are not the same.If you are a JavaScript based guy and have basic knowledge of OOP and MVC Sencha is good to go and you can switch easily and it's also mainly a JS Framework coming from ExtJS.

Comment: I also recently had an app, with the same frameworks, die on a Galaxy tab ( also running 3.1 ). Works fine in other browsers + devices ( android != 3.1, iOS ). I found out 3.1 has an inherent problem with links with querystring variables. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327  . Are you requesting any local resources (html files) and appending querystring variables to them? Is the ajax call to a remote server?

Comment: lets say: i click a link on A.html to open B.html. A.html and B.html are in phonegap project. In B.html, there is an ajax call to server. (all in my network). 

between B.html from A.html, i dont use qstring variables, just using localStorage. In B.html, i make the ajax call with querystring but number of variables never changes, but just their values.
an example for ajax call:

localhost:8000/app/x.do?callback=jQuery1703712940285913646_1321275459762
&someId=11&someeId=22&someeeId=33&someeeeId=400&_=1321275459823

btw ajaxEnabled and pushStateEnabled are set to false for jquerymobile

Comment: regarding to the link you gave, i always realized that kind of situation would happen someday for me because of the file protocol.

but it is not related to my crash :(
thanks for the link.